# Filter timestamps in a stream of text for those within last 5 minutes

Tags: shell, unix

I have a stream of output from `lpstat -o`, a tool included with CUPS for listing print queues.

The example output from lpstat -o is:

[image: screenshot of output]

How can I filter this to only include lines with a timestamp not more than 5 minutes prior to the present?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: When you give us an image, we can't copy-and-paste it as input to test our answers.

Comment: Also, please avoid tagging speculatively (for tools you think someone *could* use to answer your question); instead, only tag for tools you actually have a question or problem about, and let folks writing answers introduce other tools only as they see fit. If you actually made an attempt to use `awk`, tag for awk, and show us that attempt; if you haven't tried it yet, just tag `unix`, and standard UNIX tools (including grep or awk) will be implicitly in-scope.

Comment: Do not use image, does not help us to help you

Comment: Not to mention what would take roughly 320-bytes to store as text requires 62,163-bytes to store as your image `4MR1h.png`

Comment: Moreover, with copied-and-pasted text we could tell if the output had tabs or spaces, to better determine how to parse out the timestamp; right now, we have no way of knowing (without guessing at which version of `lpstat` you're running).

Comment: 60+ results when you search here for `[bash] filter by date`. 160+ when you search for `[bash] filter by time`.  Please update your Q with your best attempt to solve the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the date to MSB->LSB in order to compare: YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

To get the date 5 minutes ago:

`REF=$(date -d "$(date) - 5 minutes" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%s')`

Then cut the date string from the lpstat -o to compare:

`CMP=$(date -d "Mon 16 Sep 2019 06:14:49 AM EDT" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%s')`

I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Note that all-caps variable names are permitted to modify shell and operating system behavior -- see the relevant section of the POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, reserving names with at least one lowercase character for application use. (Setting any shell variable will modify a like-named environment variable, making the namespace rules apply to both types).